# Accessing files stored in emulated storage

Tags: java, android

I currently have an application that downloads files from a server and by default they are stored under /storage/emulated/0/ . I set it up so they download to a folder called "data". The files successfully download and unzip to /storage/emulated/0/data/unzipped , however, when I try to load an html file, stored under the data folder, into a webview, I get an error saying the file can't be found. I double checked the file path of the html file using Astro File Manager and was able to verify I have the right file path. Here is the statement I use to load the html file into the webview.

```
wb.loadUrl(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/data/unzipped/output.html");
```

I have tried it with and without the .html extension and still no luck. Any ideas? Are there are restrictions on accessing the emulated storage?

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() translates to /mnt/sdcard

Comment: When I log the path using Log.d("path", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()), it gives me /storage/emulated/0.

Comment: Can we see the error from the LogCat?

Comment: I don't see an error in logcat other than one that may be related that says "No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Intercept.apk". The webview says Webpage not available. The webpage at /storage/emulated/0/data/unzipped/output.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Comment: I didn't delete the file and tried just loading the html file from the location at the beginning of the program before anything else is done and I am still unable to access the html file.

Comment: Hmm, this may be due to Android 4.2 user profiles. I'm curious if there's another permission for your use case. I'll have to do some digging...

Comment: Do you have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yep, I just double checked, I have both read and write permissions, along with internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File paths are not URLs. Use the `file://` scheme to access files.